# Why do I get correct join with one table and not another when using VS 2017 and .net core 2.1

Tags: sql-server, join, razor-pages, asp.net-core-2.1

Disclaimer: I'm a newbie to Razor Pages and MVC but I'm very familiar with related databases (MS Access) and have a basic knowledge of SQL.  I have three tables in a Razor Pages Core 2.1 Database-First solution with VS 2017.  The models are Advertisement, State, and AbbrvXref.  Advertisement and State were created from the original database tables and I added AbbrvXref manually.  The scaffold generated code for the State model joins correctly with Advertisement, where I can display any column from the Advertisement table.  I cannot however display any column from the AbbrvXref table even though the scaffolded code for "index" for example, shows a join was generated.

DbContext:

```
namespace ImportSQL.Data
{
    public class SQLDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public SQLDbContext(DbContextOptions<SQLDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Advertisement> Advertisements { get; set; }
        public DbSet<State> States { get; set; }
        public DbSet<AbbrvXref> AbbrvXrefs { get; set; }


        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Advertisement>().ToTable("Event");
            modelBuilder.Entity<State>().ToTable("Ad_States");
            modelBuilder.Entity< AbbrvXref>().ToTable("StateName");
        }
    }
}
```

State Model:

```
namespace ImportSQL.Models
{
    public class State
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int AdvertisementID { get; set; }
        public string StateAbbrv { get; set; }
        public DateTime? TimeStamp { get; set; }

        public Advertisement Advertisement { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("StateAbbrv")]
        public virtual AbbrvXref AbbrvXref { get; set; }

    }

}
```

AbbrvXref Model:

```
namespace ImportSQL.Models
{
    public class AbbrvXref
    {
        [Key]
        public string StateAbbrv { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public  State State { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Scaffold generated razor page for Index:

```
namespace ImportSQL.Pages.States
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ImportSQL.Data.SQLDbContext _context;

        public IndexModel(ImportSQL.Data.SQLDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IList<State> State { get;set; }

        public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {
            State = await _context.States
                .Include(s => s.AbbrvXref)
                .Include(s => s.Advertisement).ToListAsync();
        }
    }
}

@page
@model ImportSQL.Pages.States.IndexModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}
.
.
.
@foreach (var item in Model.State) {
        <tr>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AbbrvXref.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Advertisement.ID)
            </td>

        </tr>
}
```

SQL Database tables (Note DbContext for difference in model and database table names):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StateName] (
    [StateAbbrv] NCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    [Name]       NCHAR (10) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([StateAbbrv] ASC)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Ad_States] (
    [ID]              INT          NOT NULL,
    [AdvertisementID] INT          NULL,
    [StateAbbrv]      NVARCHAR (3) DEFAULT ('ZZ') NULL,
    [Timestamp]       DATETIME     NULL
);
```